# Canvas JS How to get height and width of polygon shape?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I created a small canvas js script and draw outline on shape here is the script

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
for (let index = 1; index < coordinates.length; index++) {
    context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
}
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)";
context.fill()
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
```

But i am unable to get its width and height of shape, actually i want to display and line as tooltip for user reference.

Here i attach image you can see black line on top of Dice (i did for your reference in photoshop). i want to show that line.
i am noob, if any one can help me with example code that would be great.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57pYb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the min/max X and Y like this:

```
var minx = coordinates[0].x, maxx = coordinates[0].x, miny = = coordinates[0].y, maxy = = coordinates[0].y;
for (let index = 1; index < coordinates.length; index++) {
  if (coordinates[index].x < minx) minx = coordinates[index.x]);
  if (coordinates[index].x > maxx) maxx = coordinates[index.x]);
  if (coordinates[index].y < miny) miny = coordinates[index.y]);
  if (coordinates[index].y > maxy) maxy = coordinates[index.y]);
}
```

You can calculate height and width using the min and max values.

Comment: I am very thankful to you for quick response, but the issue is position of coordinates[0] is not always be the most left or right. it can be top or mid of shape.
i believe my requirement is not so easy it's very tricky part.

For example what if i have heart shape, and i start tracing it from top mid.

Comment: That's why you need to iterate through all the points to find the min and the max x and y values, as my answer demonstrates

Comment: I think behind the scene we need some bounding box and then get its width and height.

Comment: @Saba, you *get* the bounding box here!

Comment: Can you please help with some jsfiddle example, by doing this loop how i can get width and height of shape? and draw that line on top of shape?
I shall be very thankful to you

Comment: @trincot can you please help me how i will get Width and Height by using the above code please?

Comment: @SabaNaeem Width = maxx - minx. Height = maxy - miny

Answer (score 0):

If your polygon looks like following, this could be the fastest solution.

```
var polygon = [1678, 385, 1726, 388, 1725, 427, 1679, 427];

var minX = Math.min(...polygon.filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 0));
var maxX = Math.max(...polygon.filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 0));
var minY = Math.min(...polygon.filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 1));
var maxY = Math.max(...polygon.filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 1));

var width = maxX - minX;
var height = maxY - minY;
```